How can I configure a push consumer in C# using the nats.client library in version 2.2.0?
    //objeto de gerenciamento das stream
    NatsJSContext jetStreamContext = new(connection);

    //Criando e adicionando a stream ao nats
    string dominio = "DOMINIOCLIENTE";

    //StreamConfig configuracoesStream = new(dominio, ["DOMINIOCLIENTE.CANAL.*", "DOMINIOCLIENTE.RESPONSAVEISALUNOS.*"]);
    StreamConfig configuracoesStream = new(dominio, ["DOMINIOCLIENTE.RESPONSAVEISALUNOS.2"]);
    INatsJSStream jetStream = await jetStreamContext.CreateStreamAsync(configuracoesStream);

    int[] envolvidos = [1, 2, 3];
    int idEnvolvido = envolvidos[new Random().Next(envolvidos.Length)];
    string idInscricao = $"{dominio}.RESPONSAVEISALUNOS.{2}";

    //Criando um consumer
    //ConsumerConfig configuracaoConsumer = new();

    Console.WriteLine($"Escutando: {idInscricao}");
    INatsJSConsumer consumer = await jetStream.CreateOrUpdateConsumerAsync(new ConsumerConfig()
    {
        DeliverPolicy = ConsumerConfigDeliverPolicy.New
    });

    //await using var inscricao = await connection.SubscribeCoreAsync<string>(idInscricao);
    //At this code point, I cannot filter a specific subject, and the consumer receives all messages from the stream
    await foreach (NatsJSMsg<string> msg in consumer.ConsumeAsync<string>())
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:F} - Received: {msg.Data}");
        await msg.AckAsync();
    }

    //Desconectando
    await connection.DisposeAsync();

I tried to generate consumers, but they only have pull consumers.
In older versions of nats.client, it was possible to create push consumer configurations by specifying subjects at registration time, such as:
//jetStream.PushSubscribeAsync(subject, (object? sender, MsgHandlerEventArgs e) =>

